# Control + click acts as right-click in Ubuntu in VMWare on Mac

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I am using 18.04 and currently when I <kbd>control</kbd> + Left-click it is actually just producing a single right-click.

This is a fresh install and I would ideally like it to use the default <kbd>control</kbd> + left-click behaviour.

It is a MacBook Pro 2018 running Ubuntu inside a VM, VMWare Fusion.

Comment: And what are you trying to obtain instead?

Comment: the normal `control+left-click` functionality.

Comment: Check the mouse settings in system settings and gnome-control-center?

Comment: Ah, you may want to install  gnome-tweaks and gnome-tweak-tool to have access to finer settings.

Comment: BTW you didn't tell anything about the hardware. What is it, a Mac, a Dell, an HP? Is this a touchpad problem or a mouse problem?

Comment: Sorry all, I have added more information.

Comment: Is your host OS macOS? This looks like the default behavior of macOS. Try to work around that: Check https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118276/disable-system-wide-ctrl-click-as-right-click-in-mavericks or switch your guest to full screen which might help to circumvent some host UI behavior according to my experience with virtualization.

Comment: Ye, so I did have everything working on my old macbook pro, but I don't remember having to change any behaviour. And ye, its running in full screen :)

Comment: So please check the link. My favorite is [the most upvoted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/168318/90319) but I cannot check it myself right now. You should also [edit] your question and include your host macOS version.